# $\int_0^{\infty} e^{A^*t} e^{At} dt$ is well-defined when $\mu(A) < 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Consider $A$ a symetric matrix such that $\mu(A) = \max\{Re(\lambda). 
>  \lambda \in \sigma(A)\} < 0$.
>
> Justify that $B = \int_0^{\infty} e^{A^*t} e^{At} dt$ is well-defined.

I read that $\mu(A) < 0$ justifies well-definiteness of $B$. These are my remarks:

$\|\int_0^{t} e^{A^*t} e^{At} dt\| \le \int_{0}^t \| e^{A^*t} e^{At}\| dt \le C^2 (1+|t|)^{2d+1} e^{2 \mu(A) t} \to 0$

Here I used @SangchulLee bound. However, with this bound I'm getting that the integral converges to $0$ and this doesn't seem to make sense since $B$ should be positive definite (see related question).

**Related**

[Show that the for lyapunov equation $A^TQ+QA=-I$, the matrix $Q$ is positive definite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133714/show-that-the-for-lyapunov-equation-atqqa-i-the-matrix-q-is-positive-def)

Comment: We may write $J = D + N$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix consisting of eigenvalues of $A$ and $N$ is a nilpotent matrix satisfying $DN = ND$. Then $e^{Jt} = e^{Nt}e^{Dt}$, and since $N$ is nilpotent, $e^{Nt}$ is a polynomial of degree at most $d$, which is the size of $A$. So we have $\| e^{Nt} \| \leq C(1+|t|^d)$ for some constant $C > 0$. This easily yields $\|e^{At}\| \leq C(1+|t|^d) e^{\mu(A)t} $.

Comment: @SangchulLee than you for pointing out the bound. So I guess that integrating the bound to the square gives the existence of the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is similar to saying that the gamma function is $0$, maybe you applied a sup bound incorrectly? You can just compute the upper bound. Write $r=2|\mu(A)|>0$. Then continuing from Sangchul's bound,
\begin{align} \left\|\int_0^t e^{A^*s}e^{As}ds\right\|  
&\le 
 C^2\int_0^t(1+s^d)^2e^{2\mu(A)s}ds 
\\&=
 C^2\int_0^t(1+s^d)^2e^{-rs}ds \\
&=C^2r^{-1}\int_0^{rt} (1+(x/r)^d)^2e^{-x}dx\\
&=C^2r^{-1}\int_0^{rt}e^{-x}dx +2C^2r^{-d-1}\int_0^{rt} x^de^{-x}dx \\&\quad + C^2r^{-2d-1}\int_0^{rt} x^{2d}e^{-x}dx \\
&\xrightarrow[t\to\infty]{} C^2r^{-1} + 2C^2r^{-d-1}\Gamma(d+1) \\&\qquad +C^2r^{-2d-1}\Gamma(2d+1) \in (0,\infty)  \end{align}